# Am I understanding this VS Code API behavior correctly? Non-default *object* settings (when provided) are always merged?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VS Code Extension, and I think maybe I'm missing something in the docs, or else the behavior I'm seeing just isn't specified there, and my assumptions are wrong...?

I've defined some default settings for my extension, like so...

**package.json**

```
  "contributes": {
    "configuration": {
      "title": "ToggleSettingsChanges",
      "properties": {
        "toggleSettingsChanges.settingsToToggle": {
          "scope": "resource",
          "type": "object",
          "default": {
            "window.zoomLevel": 2,
            "editor.fontSize": 22,
            "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 16,
            "scm.diffDecorations": "none",
            "workbench.statusBar.visible": false,
            "editor.cursorBlinking": "solid",
            "workbench.activityBar.visible": false
          },
          "description": "[ snip ]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

**extension.js**

```js
// In the "main" method that runs when a command is activated:

const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("toggleSettingsChanges");
const settingsToToggle = config.get("settingsToToggle");
const inspectedSettingsToToggle = config.inspect("settingsToToggle");

console.log("settingsToToggle:", JSON.stringify(settingsToToggle), "\n\n")
console.log("inspected settingsToToggle:", JSON.stringify(inspectedSettingsToToggle), "\n\n")
return;
```

In the Extension Host instance, I can tweak and adjust the settings, to include this:

**User or Workspace Settings JSON**

```
// ... 
"toggleSettingsChanges.settingsToToggle": {
  "editor.fontSize": 11,
  "pumpkins_are_great": true
},
```

In the console output, I'm seeing the following:

```
settingsToToggle: {"window.zoomLevel":2,"editor.fontSize":11,"terminal.integrated.fontSize":16,"scm.diffDecorations":"none","workbench.statusBar.visible":false,"editor.cursorBlinking":"solid","workbench.activityBar.visible":false,"pumpkins_are_great":true} 

inspected settingsToToggle: {"key":"toggleSettingsChanges.settingsToToggle","defaultValue":{"window.zoomLevel":2,"editor.fontSize":22,"terminal.integrated.fontSize":16,"scm.diffDecorations":"none","workbench.statusBar.visible":false,"editor.cursorBlinking":"solid","workbench.activityBar.visible":false},"globalValue":{"editor.fontSize":11,"pumpkins_are_great":true}}
```

For the `settingsToToggle` line, I **expected** to see only the following settings:

```
{"editor.fontSize":11,"pumpkins_are_great":true}
```

#### **It seems** that if you provide an object default, any configuration provided is merged with that object, instead of replacing it entirely.

*Is that the case?* Have I missed this in the documentation?

It seems to me that a *value* (even an object) would be overwritten, and not simply merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation may have been updated since this question was posted.  The way it's written now, seems pretty clear to me.  I'm writing because I feel I have found a discrepancy in the API, which may help out the OP.

Reference

> **Note**: Only object value types are merged and all other value types are overridden.
>
> -- [VS Code API - WorkspaceConfiguration](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration)

---

**Additional information**

I want my default values to be merged with the user settings, as is described above.  I was confused by seeing my defaults overriden.  This question helped me understand what is happening.  I'll share my approach since OP may be interested.  My observations:

- Default values provided in `package.json` are merged with user settings, as described in the documentation (link above).
- Default values passed programmatically with `WorkspaceConfiguration.get(section, defaultValue)` **do not** exhibit the merging behavior.  It's not clear if this is intentional or not. Update: this behavior is working as intended, reference [#105598](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105598).